# Generating preview of image after being captured from camera

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-camera2

I am trying to create an app which uses custom camera using camera 2 api for clicking pictures. In my app, I want to take a picture and after taking picture, a preview of the captured image should immediately display in order to discard or accept it. I am a beginner so, it is quite confusing for me to how to do it. Below is my code for image capture:

```
private void startImageCaptureRequest() throws CameraAccessException 
{
 xadCaptureRequestBuilder=xaCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
 xadCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(xaImageReader.getSurface());
 xadCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION,xaTotalRotation);
 CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback stillCaptureCallback=new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

 @Override
 public void onCaptureStarted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, long timestamp, long frameNumber) {
 super.onCaptureStarted(session, request, timestamp, frameNumber);
  try {
                createXaFileName();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



     }
    };
    xaPreviewImageSession.capture(xadCaptureRequestBuilder.build(),stillCaptureCallback,null);
}
```

I want two consecutive images for my app.How could I do it? Please help.

Comment: What do you mean 'two consecutive images'?

Comment: means one after another..

Comment: You want two images one after another, but also immediate preview to accept the image or not. Do you mean that the preview will be displayed after the two consecutive images are ready?

Comment: I mean when I take first image it should show preview and if accepted I should be ready to take second image with camera and after again the preview of second image.

Comment: This use case is covered in the official basic camera2 sample, bit these days it is recommended to use cameraX new API when you don't need the advanced features of camera2 API.

Comment: How can I preview the captured image? Could you please guide me?